# Flutter -No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I have recently updated the android studio to Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1 and took the latest SDK versions(31). After updating the studio, my existing Flutter project is failed to build with  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi. Please see the complete log.

**Complete Log**

```
[+1608 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs
[        ] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED
[  +95 ms] w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at ..\build\kotlin\sessions
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 825 actionable tasks: 825 executed
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
[        ] > No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 3m 20s
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"eaabc68f-7957-45d7-8e88-b20c2e5e0fe6","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[ +690 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:563:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1043:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:196:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:284:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:232:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>


[{"event":"app.stop","params":{"appId":"eaabc68f-7957-45d7-8e88-b20c2e5e0fe6"}}]
[  +13 ms] "flutter run" took 2,02,547ms.
[{"id":0,"error":"app 'eaabc68f-7957-45d7-8e88-b20c2e5e0fe6' not found","trace":"#0      AppDomain.stop (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:709:7)\n#1      Domain.handleCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:220:34)\n#2      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:218:31)\n#3      Domain.handleCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:218:5)\n#4      Daemon._handleRequest (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:144:28)\n#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)\n#11     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)\n#12     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)\n#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#18     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)\n#19     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)\n#20     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)\n#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#24     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#26     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:63:11)\n#27     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:13:11)\n#28     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)\n#29     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:155:13)\n#30     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:130:5)\n#31     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:163:5)\n#32     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)\n#33     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#34     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#35     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#36     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#37     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#38     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:63:11)\n#39     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:13:11)\n#40     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)\n#41     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:243:7)\n#42     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:317:20)\n#43     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:310:5)\n#44     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)\n#45     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)\n#46     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#47     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#48     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#50     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#51     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)\n#52     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)\n#53     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)\n#54     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2160:41)\n#55     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)\n#56     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#57     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#58     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#59     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#60     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)\n#61     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)\n#62     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)\n#63     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1696:33)\n#64     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1208:14)\n#65     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)\n#66     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)\n#67     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:120:13)\n#68     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:185:5)\n"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

It is because the console log of Android studio is updating wrongly. I have a similar issue after updating android studio to Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1 and took the latest SDK versions(31). I have solved it in the following way-

**Step I**

Go to android => gradle => wrapper = gradle-wrapper.properties file and

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip` with `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{latest version}-all.zip`

You can found the latest version from the below link

https://gradle.org/releases/

**Step II**

Go to android => open build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0' 
    ...
}
```

change with the latest version

**Another easy Solution**

Create a sample flutter app after updating the studio to a higher version. Then run the sample app- It will work perfectly.

Then follow **Step I and II** and replace the value with sample project values.

**Another Solution if the above solution is not working**

Go to File=> Settings in Android Studio

Go To Plugin=> Installed Plugin

Go to Flutter Plugin=> Uninstall Plugin and Install it again- restart Studio

Comment: I have been struggling for days. You just saved me! Would you believe this also fixed an issue with a CI pipeline? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Go to your sdk folder and delete everything inside 'ndk' folder. That's it.